# On Hadwiger's conjecture for k=4.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I'm reading the article "A Survey of Hadwiger's Conjecture" by Bjarne Toft. Toft states that the following result implies Hadwiger's conjecture for the case $k=4$:

Theorem. Let $G$ be edge-maximal for the property of not having $K_4$ as a minor. Then $G$ is a $K_3$ cockade of strength 2.

For completeness's sake, a "$K_3$-cockade of strength 2" is defined recursively:

1. $K_3$ is a $K_3$-cockade of strength 2.
2. If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are disjoint $K_3$-cockades of strength 2 and $x_i y_i \in E(G_i)$ for $i=1,2$, then the graph obtained from $G_1\cup G_2$ by identifying $x_1$ with $x_2$ and $y_1$ with $y_2$ is a $K_3$-cockade of strength 2.

Hadwiger's conjecture for $k=4$ states that if a graph is 4-colorable then it has $K_4$ as a minor. So, I attempted to use the contrapositive of the given theorem to imply Hadwiger's conjecture, but I can't quite see how not being a $K_3$ cockade relates to being 4-colorable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use induction to prove that:

> if $G$ is $K_3$-cockade of strength 2 then $G$ is $3$-colorable.

Now, suppose $G$ with $\chi(G) \ge 4$, but has no $K_4$-minor. Choose $G$ to be maximal with respect to the number of edges. Then, $G$ is $K_3$-cockade of strength 2.  Therefore it is $3$-colorable. Hence, we have a contradiction.